# Error in `geom_text()` : geom_text()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to create a histogram with legends above these bars.
the legends represents the average hours of sleep per day.

```r
ggplot(average_sleep_per_day) +
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(day, average_sleep), y = average_sleep, fill = average_sleep))  +
            labs(title = "average_sleep_per_day") +
            theme_classic() +
            theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
                   plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=10, face = "bold")) +
            geom_text(aes(label = round(average_sleep, 1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 1.02))
```

My data:

```
average_sleep_per_day <- structure(
  list(
    day = c("Dimanche", "Jeudi", "Lundi"),
    average_sleep = c(7.54575757575758, 6.68828125, 6.99166666666667)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Comment: You specified `x` and `y` as local aesthetics in `geom_col`. Either make them global by moving them to ` ggplot()` or add them to aes() in geom_text too.

Comment: I tried and had this result "`geom_text()` requires the following missing aesthetics: label"

Comment: Sounds as if you removed `label=...` from `aes()` in geom_text. If you need more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: structure(
  list(
    day = c("Dimanche", "Jeudi", "Lundi"),
    average_sleep = c(7.54575757575758,
                      6.68828125, 6.99166666666667)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-3L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment the issue is that specified `x` and `y` as local aesthetics in `geom_col`. To fix that make them global by moving them to `ggplot()` as I do in the code below or add them to `aes()` in `geom_text` too.

```r
average_sleep_per_day <- structure(list(day = c("Dimanche", "Jeudi", "Lundi"), average_sleep = c(7.54575757575758, 6.68828125, 6.99166666666667)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(average_sleep_per_day, aes(x = reorder(day, average_sleep), y = average_sleep)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = average_sleep)) +
  labs(title = "average_sleep_per_day") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10, face = "bold")
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(average_sleep, 1)),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 1.02)
  )
```

[image]